# spring data neo4j 6 @Query passing list param throws ConverterNotFoundException on converting from List<Pojo> to type [org.neo4j.driver.Value]

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I tried to update relationship properties using custom query with @Query where its working with java object but not with collection<T> / List<T> as seen below:

```
@Query("UNWIND $relations \n" +
        "AS item \n" +
        "MATCH (f:PERSON {nid: $from})-[r:KNOWS]->(t:LANGUAGE {name: $to}) \n" +
        "WHERE ID(r) = item.id SET r.description = item.description \n" +
        "return f, collect(r), collect(t)")
ResponseType updateRelation(@Param("from") String from, @Param("to") String to, @Param("relations") List<KnowsEntity> relEntites);
```

when i invoke this method it throws error as follows:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [*.**KnowsEntity**] to type [**org.neo4j.driver.Value**]

Does this mean i need an custom converter to make this work?

also, when i hard-coded the json structure as below like we do in neo4j browser, it works fine.

Note: with subject to the keys should not be in quotes!

```
@Query("UNWIND [{description:\"defining value\",id:0},{description:\"blah blah\",id:3}] \n" +
        "AS item \n" +
        "MATCH (f:PERSON {nid: $from})-[r:KNOWS]->(t:LANGUAGE {name: $to}) \n" +
        "WHERE ID(r) = item.id SET r.description = item.description \n" +
        "return f, collect(r), collect(t)")
ResponseType updateRelation(@Param("from") String from, @Param("to") String to);
```

Please correct me whether am i missing something / any better way to get this updated using list of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for asking this, I think this is just a missing feature: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2292

Comment: Its working if we create collection in the app itself, but not relaying via http payload. If someone know how to get around this. Please do suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The fix [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2292) is working in locally build inputs. Thanks [@Michael Simons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67999546/4527149)

But, if the input is via http payload, then we need Entity level change for **@RequestBody** to get serialized and pass through the SDN.

```
@RelationshipProperties
@Data
public class KnowsEntity {

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class) // it might not be needed
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @Property
    private Boolean read;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @Property
    private Boolean write;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @TargetNode
    private Language language;

}

@Node(primaryLabel = "LANGUAGE")
public class Language {

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @Id
    private String name;

}

public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }
}
```

and in controller get param as

```
@RequestBody @JsonView(Views.Public.class) Set<KnowsEntity> knows
```